# GDB Debugging applications using clone()

Tags: linux, debugging, multithreading, gdb, clone

Is there a GUI for GDB that will allow me to debug applications that create threads using clone() syscall? I tried Insight and KDBG, but for some reason when the new cloned thread is created, I can't see it in the thread list. The clone syscall is called through inline assembly. Is it not possible because the thread created shares PID with the original process? (it has a unique TID though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 set follow-fork-mode child
```

I don't use a gdb GUI. Sometimes `gdb -tui` if I am feeling flirty.